# Multiple Custom Cells in UITableView With Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a tableview that has two custom cells in it, with the information being pulled from Firebase Database.  The first custom cell displays the dates, and the second custom cell displays the events.  When I run the app, the tableview is only returning the first custom cell, which is the dates. What would be causing this?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class augustController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var augustController: UITableView!

    var ref = DatabaseReference()

    var date = [String]()
    var event = [String]()

    var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle = 0
    var databaseHandle2:DatabaseHandle = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref.child("Events").child("August").child("dates").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let post = snapshot.value as? String
            if let actualPost = post {
                self.date.append(actualPost)
            }
        }

        databaseHandle2 = ref.child("Events").child("August").child("events").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let post2 = snapshot.value as? String
            if let actualPost2 = post2 {
                self.event.append(actualPost2)
                self.augustController.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return date.count
    }

    func tableView2(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return event.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {            
        let augustDate = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "augustDate") as! dateCell
        augustDate.date.text = date[indexPath.row]

        return(augustDate)
    }

    func tableView2(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let augustEvents = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "augustEvents") as! eventCell
        augustEvents.even.text = event[indexPath.row]

        return(augustEvents)
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that you've indicated that this question has been answered, please go back through your earlier question and do the same where appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You implement `cellForRow` twice , you have to

```
var itemsArr = [Item]()
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return itemsArr.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let item = itemsArr[indexPath.row]

   if item.isDate {

     let augustDate = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "augustDate") as! dateCell
     augustDate.date.text = item.content
     return augustDate

 }
 else {

    let augustEvents = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "augustEvents") as! eventCell
    augustEvents.even.text = item.content
    return augustEvents
 }
}
```

//

then make it one array and append items of this struct type

```
struct Item {
   var isDate:Bool
   var content:String
}
```

Comment: There's also two `numberOfRowsInSection` methods. A lot more needs to be fixed than just combing the two `cellForRowAt` methods.

Comment: @Sh_Khan in the viewDidLoad will it still be  `self.event.append(actualPost2)` and `self.date.append(actualPost)` or will they both be `self. itemsArr.append(actualPost2)` and `self. itemsArr.append(actualPost)`